# iOS Evenly space 5 labels in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel, autolayout, constraints

I have a prototype cell that I use to display some data. I am trying to apply constraints to it so that the 5 labels dynamically space evenly depending on what device is used to display them. So far, all I have been able to do is to add constraints with constant values that cause the labels to disappear off screen on small display devices. How do I add constraints so that they are evenly spaced between one another? Thanks.

[image: UITableViewCell with 5 UILabels]

Edit:

[image]

iPhone 6:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a list of constraints you'll need to make this happen:

1st label:

- Leading to container, top/bottom to container

2nd-4th labels:

- Top Alignment + Bottom Alignment to 1st
- Equal Width to 1st

5th label:

- Top+Bottom+Equal Width to the first
- Trailing to container

Finally:

- And between any two adjacent labels, add a 0 horizontal space constraint.

After you get all of those set up, click the little Triangle constraint tool in the bottom right and update frames. They should all snap into place!

Here is a pic of the final outcome in a storyboard.

[image: Constraints with names]

Comment: Your picture answered my question! Ha!

Comment: Yep yep. Added a picture because of your comment but I couldn't add the pic in a comment hah.

Comment: Do you mind giving names to the labels so I can see which labels the constraints are applied to? Thanks

Comment: I had named them so it would be easier but I had to reopen Xcode for it to update the labels in the constraints section. Go figure.

Comment: So I have applied this and it seems to work but my label widths are decreasing and so the text is being truncated with ellipsis... I don't necessarily want equal widths of all labels. 2,3,4,5 can be equal but 1 needs to be constant.

Comment: Ah I see. Well then just make 3/4/5 have equal widths to 2 and fix up label 1 with a constant width constraint. Shouldn't be too bad =)

Comment: I have done that, see my updated question for results.

Comment: It appears the horizontal spacing is a constant value causing the labels to resize instead of a percentage...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64887/discussion-between-acey-and-jon-erickson).